# Sum column based on variable name in other column that contains x following similar letters

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, aggregate

I have a table that is somewhat like this:

| var | RC |
| --- | --- |
| distance50 | 2 |
| distance20 | 4 |
| precMax | 5 |
| precMin | 1 |
| total_prec | 8 |
| travelTime | 5 |
| travelTime | 2 |

I want to sum all similar type variables, resulting in something like this:

| var | sum |
| --- | --- |
| dist | 6 |
| prec | 14 |
| trav | 7 |

Using 4 letters is enough to separate the different types. I have tried and tried but not figured it out. Could anyone please assist? I generally try to work with dplyr, so that would be preferred. The datasets are small (n<100) so speed is not required.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate(var, c("var", "b"), sep = "[_A-Z0-9]", extra = "merge") %>% 
  group_by(var = ifelse(b %in% var, b, var)) %>% 
  summarize(RC = sum(RC), .groups = "drop")
```

1. `separate` `var` into two columns by splitting on underscores (`_`), capital letters `A-Z` or numbers `0-9`.
2. In the `group_by` statement, if the second column can be found in the first then fill the first column.
3. Lastly, sum `RC` by group.

**Output**

```
  var         RC
  <chr>    <int>
1 distance     6
2 prec        14
3 travel       7
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
aggregate(
  RC ~ var,
  data = transform(
    with(df, df[!(grepl("total", var)),]),
    var = gsub("^(\\w+)([A-Z0-9]\\w+$)", "\\1", var)
  ),
  FUN = sum
)
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(var = c("distance50", "distance20", "precMax", 
"precMin", "total_prec", "travelTime", "travelTime"), RC = c(2L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tibble(
    var=c('dista', 'distb', 'travelTime'),
    rc=2:4) %>% 
    print() %>% 

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  var           rc
#  <chr>      <int>
#1 dista          2
#2 distb          3
#3 travelTime     4

    group_by(var=str_sub(var, end=4)) %>% 
    print() %>% 

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   var [2]
#  var      rc
#  <chr> <int>
#1 dist      2
#2 dist      3
#3 trav      4

    summarise(sum=sum(rc))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  var     sum
#  <chr> <int>
#1 dist      5
#2 trav      4
```